# Google analytics events not showing up

Tags: google-analytics

New to google analytics so bear with me. I added the event tracking to my code, but when i check in the reporting behavior event tab it's blank. Here is my code.

```
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
```

here is an example of my a tag

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" class="app-logo" ga('send', 'event', 'Link', 'Click', 'example.com');>
```

Comment: Did you look at the realtime tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this just a typo in your example, but you are missing the event handler in your link:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" class="app-logo" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Link', 'Click', 'example.com');"></a>
```

The event handler ("onclick") is the bit that specifies which action shall trigger the javascript code. If you just dump the event call in the HTML it will not even be recognized as JS.

Comment: that's what i was missing. Thank you very much, nothing is showing up now but im sure there is a 24hr turn around, right?

Comment: You should be seeing events in the realtime tab, plus you could use a tool like Google Tag Assistant (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) to confirm if everything is working. But yes, there is some delay due to processing time.

Answer (score 56):

In google-analytics, for the correct website, look on the "realtime/events" page and see if events are appearing there (they should appear here within a few seconds, after being triggered on your website).

If not, you *might* have added a filter, to filter out events generated by traffic from your own IP. You can find this filter under "admin" and then "all filters". If so, remove it (or temporarily change the IP-address, so it doesn't match). After that, generate a few events on your website and look again on the google-analytics page, under realtime traffic / events page.

If they work under realtime, it should also work in non-realtime (but it might take 24-48 hours to appear there!)

Comment: The most valuable comment to debug the issue!

Comment: Any advice on what might cause events to show up in real-time, but not in the non-realtime data?

Comment: Local IP address being blocked was my issue too. I hopped on a VPN and events started coming right through. This tip helped me a lot.

Comment: Another common cause of this problem is Google Tag Manager issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40761709/2898283